# Is it considered bad drupal style to have a large number of 'static' pages scattered around the website?

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I'm developing a website in Drupal 7 which has a large number of pages that are either A) static, or B) dynamic in some sense, but not abstractable into a node.

My first instinct would be to just add implementing menu items in a `hook_menu()` function, then add `hook_theme()`, theme files, etc. etc. The thing is, across my website, I'll have probably 15 or more of these pages - that's a lot of URL's that are hard-coded into this site, in a way that isn't necessarily obvious to content managers who will be maintaining it.

The thing is, all of these hard-coded pages are going to be in the context of a landing-page. I am toying with the idea of creating a landing page content type, where they can edit the basic pieces (pretty much just the title and a single sentence) and assign it to a menu item, but then allowing them to select from a variety of pre-hard-coded solutions for each of the possible necessary pages. This is also a very sloppy solution, but it will give the content manager a tiny bit of control.

The pages in question are all too different, with too specific of requirements to make use of any module such as Views - they all need to be one-off, server-side code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at panels for assembling smaller pieces of content into a larger piece? Or even panel nodes which is a bit more lightweight than panels but allows layout and inclusion of other page elements in a regular node.